Simpler proof of the convergence of the entries of matrix powers when eigenvalues are either of norm less than one or real
Given a matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying either $|\lambda_i| < 1$ or $\lambda_i \geq 1$ (both may be satisfied for $i\neq j$), it is true that the entries of $A^k$ converge either to a number or to $\pm \infty$ (i.e., the entries don't oscilate). One way to prove this fact is to use the jordan decomposition and to explicitly identify the entries of the powers of the Jordan blocks, but this is quite verbose. Is there a more direct approach, say based on the eigenvalues alone?
